# Why am I getting a stackoverflow?

Tags: clojure

I've been playing around with Clojure and I managed to blow the stack. In this piece of code, I use recursion only with recur. I am doing a lot of concatenation (note calls to concat in the trace below). I tried to doall on all concatenated lists, since these are lazy and I wanted them evaluated as I went along. I still get a stack overflow. Here's the trace. I am thinking this might be a common issue and someone with more experience hacking clojure can point me in the right direction.

Here's the piece of code that was causing the problem.

```
(defn move-split [[xs ys]] (doall (concat (list (concat xs (list (first ys))))  (list (next ys)))))
```

I put the doall in there because of the stackoverflow, but that still did not solve the problem.

```
(defn move-split [[xs ys]] (doall (concat (list (doall (concat xs (list (first ys))))  ) (doall (list (next ys)))   )))
```

Notice the extra doalls? Here, everwhere I call concat I filter the result through a doall. Stackoverflow gone.

doall does not seem to be recursive. That is nested lists that are also results of concat are not evaluated. What do you think?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at jline.ConsoleRunner.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError (bubble_sort2.clj:0)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:5820)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:221)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:273)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:409)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:365)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:122)
    at clojure.core$concat$fn__3450.invoke(core.clj:599)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:450)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:122)
    at clojure.core$concat$fn__3450.invoke(core.clj:599)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:450)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:122)
    at clojure.core$concat$fn__3450.invoke(core.clj:599)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:450)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:122)
    at clojure.core$concat$fn__3450.invoke(core.clj:599)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:450)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:122)
    at clojure.core$concat$fn__3450.invoke(core.clj:599)
```

Comment: Posted with additional comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're piling up a bunch of lazy operations all in a row, building up an expression like

```
(concat (concat (concat ... [3]) [2]) [1])
```

or similar. In order to determine even the first element in the resulting list, the compiler must drill deeply into this stack of functions you've given it. Try to structure your code so that this doesn't happen, or throw in a (doall) every so often to force eager/strict computations. I can't really go into more detail with just a stack trace, though - code would help.

Comment: Some code posted. Nested concats are the problem. I suspected that before I posted this. But I found that I had to pair a doall with every concat.

Answer (score 2):

Adding another answer now that OP has put up some source code and asked what's effectively a different question. If this is wrong, someone edit me appropriately.

It looks like you're converting [[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7]] into [[1 2 3 4 5] [6 7]]. Lists and lazy concats are really not the right solution to this problem, which is one of the reasons it's causing you so much pain. My instinct would be to start with a vector [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] that you keep around permanently, and construct subvecs of that vector as necessary. `subvec` is cheap and fast, both to construct and to use.

For example:

```
(defn vector-split [v at]
  [(subvec v 0 at) (subvec v at)])
```

Comment: That move-split function is clearly not the way to go and I had moved away from it, but it bothered me that I didn't know why it was causing problems. I think I understand now. And thanks for the suggestion. Something else for my clojure toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what inputs are causing your function to blow up. I can't get it to blow up with two 5-billion-element subsequences:

```
boot.user=> (defn move-split [[xs ys]]
       #_=>   (doall
       #_=>     (concat
       #_=>       (list (concat xs (list (first ys))))
       #_=>       (list (next ys)))))
#'boot.user/move-split
boot.user=> (def x (move-split [(range 5e0) (range 5e0)]))
#'boot.user/x
boot.user=> x
((0 1 2 3 4 0) (1 2 3 4))
boot.user=> (def x (move-split [(range 5e9) (range 5e9)]))
#'boot.user/x
boot.user=> (-> (nth x 0) first)
0
boot.user=> (-> (nth x 1) first)
1
```

There are, however, many opportunities to make this function more idiomatic. Looking at the function:

```
(defn move-split [[xs ys]]
  (doall
    (concat
      (list (concat xs (list (first ys))))
      (list (next ys)))))
```

On line 4: we needn't construct a `list` since `concat` is already returning a sequence. Similarly, we neeedn't construct the `list` on line 5 either, `next` is already returning a sequence. With these two changes:

```
(defn move-split [[xs ys]]
  (doall
    (concat
      (concat xs (list (first ys)))
      (next ys))))
```

Now why in the world would we mess up a perfectly good (lazy) function by sticking a `doall` at the top? Let's get rid of that. Also, since the function needs to return a two-element sequence, why not just do that instead of calling `concat` on line 3? The idiomatic way to construct a two-element sequence is via the vector literal syntax. With these two changes we have:

```
(defn move-split [[xs ys]]
  [(concat xs (list (first ys)))(next ys)])
```

Oh and we can apply vector literal syntax again, in place of that `list` constructor, giving us this final version:

```
(defn move-split [[xs ys]]
  [(concat xs [(first ys)])(next ys)])
```

Now let's try this fn out…

```
boot.user=> (defn move-split [[xs ys]]
       #_=>   [(concat xs [(first ys)])(rest ys)])
#'boot.user/move-split
boot.user=> [(range 5e0) (range 5e0)]
[(0 1 2 3 4) (0 1 2 3 4)]
boot.user=> (def x (move-split [(range 5e0) (range 5e0)]))
#'boot.user/x
boot.user=> x
[(0 1 2 3 4 0) (1 2 3 4)]
boot.user=> (-> (nth x 0) first)
0
boot.user=> (-> (nth x 1) first)
1
```

That seems to work. What if we have two huge subsequences? Let's try it with a couple 5-billion-element subsequences:

```
boot.user=> (def x (move-split [(range 5e9) (range 5e9)]))
#'boot.user/x
boot.user=> (-> (nth x 0) first)
0
boot.user=> (-> (nth x 1) first)
1
```

To your original question, as I said, I don't know what inputs were causing the original function to blow the stack. I did see this in the [`concat` doc](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/concat) documentation:

> Concatenated concatenations do not flatten automatically! Thus clj::clojure.core/reduce with concat will generate hugely nested structures and can easily generate stack overflows when attempting to walk the resulting sequence. (apply concat ...) should be preferred.

Let's use `reduce` to `concat` a sequence of 10 sequences of 10 integers:

```
boot.user=> (take 5 (reduce concat [] (for [x (range 1e1)] (range 1e1))))
(0 1 2 3 4)
```

But if we try to use `reduce` to `concat` a sequence of 10,000 sequences of 10 integers::

```
boot.user=> (take 5 (reduce concat [] (for [x (range 1e5)] (range 1e1))))

java.lang.StackOverflowError:
```

Using `apply` instead works fine:

```
boot.user=> (take 5 (apply concat (for [x (range 1e5)] (range 1e1))))
(0 1 2 3 4)
```

Just something to keep in mind when applying `concat` recursively.